# template<> for the explicit specialization of a member enumeration

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

According to 17.7.3 [temp.expl.spec] paragraph 5 ([N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)),

> ... Members of an explicitly specialized class template are defined in the same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the `template<>` syntax. The same is true when defining a member of an explicitly specialized member class. **However, `template<>` is used in defining a member of an explicitly specialized member class template that is specialized as a class template.**

The explicit specialization of `E` definitely does not belong to the bold case, and it still needs `template<>`. Why is that?

```
template<class T> struct A {
    enum E : T;
};

template<> enum A<int>::E : int { eint };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This paragraph is related to members of an explicitly specialized class template, but you have not explicitly specialized the class template.  This is an example of the case it is talking about:

```
template<class T> struct A {
    enum E : T;
};

template<> struct A<int> {
    enum E : int;
};

enum A<int>::E : int { eint }; // no template<> here
```

In your example code, you have explicitly specialized a member of the primary template, which does require using `template<>`, as specified in the first paragraph.

> 1 An explicit specialization of any of the following:
>
> ...
>
> (1.7) — member enumeration of a class template
>
> ...
>
> can be declared by a declaration introduced by template<>; that is:
> explicit-specialization:
> template < > declaration

The underlying principle behind paragraph 5 is that once you've explicitly specialized a template, it is no longer a template, and you work with the specialization just like you would any other non-template entity.

Comment: I'm talking about the explicit specialization for the member of the class template specialization **that is implicitly instantiated**. Furthermore, your code gives me an error.

Comment: @Il-seobBae: Yes, but that's not what the paragraph you mentioned from the standard is talking about.  It's talking about an explicitly specialized class template, not an explicitly specialized member, and the bold part is talking about an explicitly specialized member class template, which is something different altogether.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. Then, what paragraph necessitates the presence of `template<>` in this case? My point here is that the code does not belong to the case you mentioned, so it shouldn't need `template<>`.

Comment: @Il-seobBae: It's in the first paragraph.

Comment: I was mistaken. But, why does your code produce an error?

Comment: @Il-seobBae Not every compiler implements *every* feature of the Standard. Also, sometimes bugs creep in. clang compiles the code fine for example.

Comment: Can you check if `A<int> a;` does not produce an error? I got this message from gcc : `error: cannot add an enumerator list to a template instantiation`.

Comment: @Il-seobBae: I don't get an error: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d4c896fc6ab1586

Comment: Thank you for guiding me! Have a nice day.